# The convert between YCbCr and RGB on python

Tags: python, matlab, rgb

I want to write some image processing code on python.

```
A = imread('Example.bmp');
B  = ycbcr2rgb(rgb2ycbcr(A));
psnr(A,B) 
%= 52.7283
```

However , when I try to do the same thing on python 
the psnr is lower then the result of matlab.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
from skimage.measure import compare_psnr

A = Image.open('Example.bmp')
B = A.convert('YCbCr').convert('RGB')
compare_psnr(numpy.asarray(A),numpy.asarray(B))
# = 44.7441927214
```

There is no any problem of the psnr function on both python/matlab , I am sure that they are the same, beacuse i have tried to output the image and measure them on both python/matlab.

The problem is , why a got a lower psnr when i do convert on Python ?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44944455/4183191

Comment: I asked it earlier but unfortunately no one answer me at that time.