# PSNR values differ in matlab implementation and python

Tags: matlab, opencv, numpy, octave, mse

I have implemented a python code for calculating PSNR values of Y channel in YCrCb channel.
I get the PSNR values to be around 35.7dB(for a pair of images)

```
import cv2, main
import sys

i1 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
i2 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[2])

i1= cv2.cvtColor(i1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
i2= cv2.cvtColor(i2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

print(main.psnr(i1[:,:,0], i2[:,:,0]))
```

In main psnr is defined as:

```
def psnr(target, ref):
    import cv2
    target_data = numpy.array(target, dtype=numpy.float64)
    ref_data = numpy.array(ref,dtype=numpy.float64)

    diff = ref_data - target_data
    print(diff.shape)
    diff = diff.flatten('C')

    rmse = math.sqrt(numpy.mean(diff ** 2.))

    return 20 * math.log10(255 / rmse)
```

I got an online implementation(from the paper I am referring to) in matlab
I get PSNR values to be around 37.06dB (for the same pair of images)

```
function psnr=compute_psnr(im1,im2)
if size(im1, 3) == 3,
    im1 = rgb2ycbcr(im1);
    im1 = im1(:, :, 1);
end

if size(im2, 3) == 3,
    im2 = rgb2ycbcr(im2);
    im2 = im2(:, :, 1);
end

imdff = double(im1) - double(im2);
imdff = imdff(:);

rmse = sqrt(mean(imdff.^2));
psnr = 20*log10(255/rmse)
```

Can this error be due to errors introduced by numpy or accuracy numpy seems to achieve?

Comment: Run both functions with various small test data to see if there is a difference. If yes, then debug. E.g. `psnr([1], [2])` or `psnr([1, 2], [4, 3])` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two conversion functions seem to produce wildly different results:

> Python output:
>   [image]

> Octave output:
>   [image]

which explains the discrepancy.

Octave does mention there are several YCbCr standards:

```
 The formula used for the conversion is dependent on two constants,
 KB and KR which can be specified individually, or according to
 existing standards:

 "601" (default)
      According to the ITU-R BT.601 (formerly CCIR 601) standard.
      Its values of KB and KR are 0.114 and 0.299 respectively.
 "709" (default)
      According to the ITU-R BT.709 standard.  Its values of KB and
      KR are 0.0722 and 0.2116 respectively.
```

Maybe the python version is using a different standard? (or maybe it's a BGR vs RGB issue?). In any case, that's where the discrepancy lies, it doesn't seem to be a matter of numpy precision (when those functions are tested separately with identical inputs, they produce the same results).

**EDIT:**

According to these:

- [Why is the Y, converted by rgb2ycbcr in the Matlab, in the range [16, 235]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561915/why-is-the-y-converted-by-rgb2ycbcr-in-the-matlab-in-the-range-16-235)
- http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_ycrcb
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion

python (or rather, the opencv library) seems to be outputting the 'analog' (unscaled) version, whereas matlab / octave is outputting the 'digital' (scaled) version.

This is confirmed:

```
# Python
RGB = numpy.concatenate(
  ( numpy.array([[[0], [255], [255], [0],   [0],   [0],   [255]]], dtype=numpy.uint8),
    numpy.array([[[0], [0],   [255], [255], [255], [0],   [255]]], dtype=numpy.uint8),
    numpy.array([[[0], [0],   [0],   [0],   [255], [255], [255]]], dtype=numpy.uint8)),
  axis=2)

RGB2Y = cv2.cvtColor(RGB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
print(RGB2Y)
```

> ```
> [[[  0 128 128]
>   [ 29 107 255]
>   [179   0 171]
>   [150  21  43]
>   [226 149   1]
>   [ 76 255  85]
>   [255 128 128]]]
> ```

```
% Octave
pkg load image;
RGB = uint8 (cat (3, [0, 255, 255, 0,   0,   0,   255], ...
                     [0, 0,   255, 255, 255, 0,   255], ...
                     [0, 0,   0,   0,   255, 255, 255]));
RGB2Y = rgb2ycbcr(RGB)
```

> ```
> RGB2Y =
>  ans(:,:,1) =
>    16   81  210  145  170   41  235
>  ans(:,:,2) =
>    128   90   16   54  166  240  128
>  ans(:,:,3) =
>    128  240  146   34   16  110  128
> ```

Therefore, if it's a matter of achieving consistency, I would scale the python results using the conversion formula from analog to digital, mentioned in the wikipedia page above i.e.:

[image]

If it's a question of "which version is the most appropriate one for the calculation of PSNR", I don't know, but from what I'm reading in the links above, my money would be on the matlab / octave implementation.

Comment: Tried that.. The thing is RMSE is itself a float64. So it would calculate a float.

Comment: I had confirmed that opencv takes BGR values(from their sample codes). Also changed that; but the results are same. I want to compare my values of psnr (from a output of python code and a standard image) with another set of results available from a paper which are implemented in matlab/octave. Is there any way to solve this that writing the image files and then using octave to calculate psnr? Thank you for bring it into notice.

Comment: Well, like I said, the "psnr calculation" bit is fine both in python and octave, the problem seems to be before that during the image conversion stage. But yes, if you want to try offloading stuff to octave from python, you can try using the [oct2py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oct2py) python module. I have updated the answer with some more information regarding the reason why the conversion is different.